# Block commenting in Gedit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gedit

Is there a way to comment out a chunk of highlighted code?

I am programming in ruby, and I hate putting # on lines individually.

Comment: Ugh, all the suggestions to use block commenting miss the point, IMO: not as easy or intuitive. IMO.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

1.Install gedit plugins

```
 sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

2.Go to Edit->Preference->Plugins-> and enable Code Comment

3.Ctl+m to comment block of codes

4.Ctl+Shift+m to uncomment block of codes

Comment: I appreciate this answer because some languages don't have multiline comment support; this makes life much easier!

Comment: worked for me for `c++` by inserting `//`,, no clue if that's the comment for Ruby, or if gedit looks at the file extension (`.cpp` in my case) and chooses the comment characters accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin seems to have been discontinued.

Comment: Just installed it today, this is perfect.  And the size changer one is useful too.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby has block commenting...

```
=begin
    Insert comment here
=end
```

This will avoid the need to add # to each line... However, I don't think Gedit will convert highlighted code into commented lines by default.

Answer (score 4):

Code Comment plugin obviously is a good one for # (hash) style commenting but what if you need comment out php code block with double // slashes or any other custom commenting style? For example, with one or two whitespaces added after the comment symbol.

1. Go to Edit->Preferences->Plugins-> and enable External Tools plugin.
2. Go to Tools->Manage External Tools.
3. Under the Tools side bar click add (+) sign, call your new tool "Comment out" and add this code into the Edit field:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `# comment out current selection`

   `# comment style`

   `comment="// "`

   `xargs -i -d\\\n echo $comment{}`
4. Set up your tool.

Shortcut Key: Alt+/ 
(put the cursor in the field and press Alt+/ or any other keys)

Save: Nothing

Input: Current selection (default to document)

Output: Replace current selection

Applicability: All documents?  All languages? (change if you need)

To uncomment commented block of code do the same things except below ones.

1. Name of the Tool: "Uncomment".
2. Shortcut Key:  Alt+Backspace
3. Code to insert into the Edit field:

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `# uncomment current selection`

   `# comment symbols to remove`

   `uncomment="^\/\/ "`

   `xargs -i -d\\\n echo {} | sed -ne "s/$uncomment//p"`

Change comment/uncomment variable value  (double slashes and space) with your desired commenting style.

Enjoy.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks for the recipe!  Highly recommend to any gedit users out there.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a multi-line comment.

Example:

```
=begin
Anything between a line consisting only of =begin
and a line consisting only of =end
is treated as a comment.
=end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=begin

Code to be commented out

=end
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Code Comment plugin would do it? http://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins

Answer (score 1):

Get the "code comment" plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [gmate](https://github.com/gmate/gmate)! It is a package of cool plugins for Ruby (and not only Ruby) developement under gedit.

You can comment and uncomment bunch of lines like in Sublime or TextMate